# Is there a tool that lets me cut video with frame precision?

Tags: video-editor, compression, keyframes, virtualdub

I'm able to use Avidemux with enough ease and it's mostly enough for my video need. I can also choose codecs to recompress the video.

Unfortunately, it doesn't let me cut video outside the scope of keyframes, even when I recompress. I'm not really willing to pay for an expensive software, and I'm not sure I need DaVinci Resolve to do just this.

I know VirtualDub is not developed anymore. Are there other tools that would do frame by frame selection?

I guess I'm able to use FFmpeg too, I guess I could do with a script, but it's not really easy either.

Answer (score 1):

You may use free open source [AviSynth+](https://github.com/pinterf/AviSynthPlus/releases/tag/r2420-MT) — it's a scripting language with the very good [documentation](http://avisynth.nl/index.php/Main_Page).

Example:

```
clip   = AviSource("MyVideo.avi")    # Reading clip from disk
clip   = clip.ShowFrameNumber        # Showing frame numbers of individual frames

part1  = clip.Trim(   0,  1000)      # Selecting frames with numbers 0 to 1000
part2  = clip.Trim(8000, 12000)      # --- similar ---

result = part1 + part2               # Joining two parts
return result                        # This will be the resulting clip
```

---

*Note:*

The second command

```
clip   = clip.ShowFrameNumber
```

is used only in working process to see frame numbers, in the final result you have to remove it.